# sql left join issue not giving result of non matching from right table

Tags: sql

i want all records from left table and matching record from right table but below query not giving correct result:

```
select a.date,b.amt,b.code,c.type
from (select date from t where date is between '2017-04-01' and '2018-09-30')a
    on a.date = b.date and a.name = b.name left join
    c on c.date = b.date and c.name = b.name or c.name is null
group by a.date,b.amt,b.code,c.type
```

I cant see value for all code from table b.Its returning only matching from table c

Comment: Your code is not syntactically correct.  It would also help if you explained what you want to do.  Your question suggests two tables, but your query refers to more than two.

Comment: I have three tables in query .I want amt and code from table b and type from table c on the basis of date column

Comment: mysqli and sa tags don't make much sense together. I removed them. Consider to tag the actual DBMS you're using though.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `LEFT JOIN`, you are taking all the rows from the first table and if there are no matches for the first join condition, the resulting records for table x will be a NULL record which is why you're using the AND operator 'c.name IS NULL' but I think you have some issues with your query. It's been a while for me so I'm trying not to make an error here but you don't appear to have a table name in your FROM clause and your select can't be in the from clause (i don't think)...maybe I'm wrong but I had to clean up the statement to understand what you are doing better...so please clarify and I can improve my answer.

```
SELECT 
   [a].[date] AS 'Date'
  ,[b].[amt]  AS 'Amount'
  ,[b].[code] AS 'Code'
  ,[c].[type] AS 'Type'

FROM [table].[name] (NOLOCK)
  LEFT JOIN [table].[name] (NOLOCK) date ON [c].[date] = [b].[date]
  LEFT JOIN [table].[name] (NOLOCK) name ON [c].[name] = [b].[name]

WHERE (SELECT date 
       FROM [t]
       WHERE DATEADD (hh,-6, DATEADD (ss,[table].[name],'1970')) BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2018-09-30')
   AND [a].[date] = [b].[date] //Not sure if this is what you meant
   AND [a].[name] = [b].[name]
   AND [c].[name] IS NULL

GROUP BY [a].[date],[b].[amt],[b].[code],[c].[type]
```

Comment: you can have select clause in from statement which is called as Nested select statement. my first part that is left join between table a and table b is working fine but table b and table c is not giving result of left join It is treating it as inner join

Answer (score 0):

With some guesswork involved, I could imagine you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t.date,
       b.amt,
       b.code,
       c.type
       FROM t
            LEFT JOIN b
                      ON b.date = t.date
                         AND b.name = t.name
            LEFT JOIN c
                      ON c.date = b.date
                         AND (c.name = b.name
                               OR c.name is null)
       WHERE t.date BETWEEN '2017-04-01'
                            AND '2018-09-30';
```

- Your subquery from `t` isn't really needed, that check on `date` can be moved in the `WHERE` clause. But it wasn't strictly wrong. It depends on what the optimizer makes of it what's better.
- Though your `GROUP BY` has the same effect, I changed it to a `DISTINCT`, which might be more clear to understand at a glance.
- And I'm not sure about your join condition for `c`.

  - I guessed you want the `date` to match but allow `c.name` to be null if it doesn't match. That means you have to use parenthesis to counter the higher precedence of `AND` over `OR`.
  - You probably want to change the `b.`s in the join condition to `t.`s, if record from `c` should also be added if no matching record from `b` exists for a record from `t`. Like it is right now, no record from `c` is joined for a record from `t` without a matching record from `b`.